# Maximize the minimum entry of a surface determined by a positive definite quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, quadratic-forms, correlation

I am in need of help with this problem. Suppose we have a $d\times d$ positive definite matrix $R$ whose diagonal entries are all $1$ (like a correlation matrix), denote the inverse matrix of $R$ by $S$. Consider the set (denoted by $C$) of all points $y\in\mathbb{R}^d$ satisfying the following equation:
$$y^TSy=1.$$
The problem troubling me is, how can I maximize the minimum coordinate of points on $C$, namely I want to determine
$$\max_{y\in C}(\min_{i\in\{1,2,...,d\}}y_i),$$
I know the range of searching can be confined to the subset $\{y\in C|y_i>0,\ \forall i\}$, and the case $d=2$ is not difficult since equations describing $C$ in this case are all in the form of
$$y_1^2-2\rho y_1y_2+y_2^2=1-\rho^2,$$
where $\rho$ ranges in $(-1,1)$. The maximum must be attained at the only intersection of the line $y_2=y_1$ and $C$ in the first quadrant. But the case $d\geq 3$ seems complex and I have no idea till now.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to reformulate as follows.  Let $z$ represent the $\min$. Then the problem is to maximize $z$ subject to:
\begin{align}
z &\le y_i &&\text{for $i\in\{1,2,\dots,d\}$} \\
y^T S y &= 1
\end{align}

Comment: I've tried considering in the opposite direction by choosing a point on the line $y_1=...=y_d=:y$ and draw hyperplanes $y_1=y$, $y_2=y$,...,$y_d=y$ with other entries above $y$.  As $y$ moves downward to the origin, there will be a moment at which one of the hyperplanes touches $C$ for the first time, and the commensurate $y$ will be the answer. However the problem is that when $d\geq 3$, the moving point we choose, which is the vertex of all hyperplanes, may not always be the first one touching $C$ if $C$ is "badly" rotated, which never occurs when $d=2$, and that is where I got stuck.